# Why does the Analyzer warn about "uninitialized value"?

Tags: objective-c, clang-static-analyzer

I got this Analyzer warning

> Argument in message expression is an uninitialized value

with a little orange arrow under the second square bracket on the second line of the following code

```
- (NSString *)base64EncodedString
{
    size_t outputLength;
    char *outputBuffer =
        NewBase64Encode([self bytes], [self length], true, &outputLength);



    NSString *result =
        [[[NSString alloc]
            initWithBytes:outputBuffer
            length:outputLength
            encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]
        autorelease];
    free(outputBuffer);
    return result;
}
```

I am not sure what is causing this I have tried several things but never have I had this type of Analyzer warning.

How do I get rid of this Analyzer warning?

Comment: Are "outputBuffer" and "outputLength" initialized in all cases?

Comment: Hrmm I didnt even know they were the issue. Looking at the code. They are both declared in another method further up in the code. However it dose not seem that they are global vars.

Comment: declaration is not initialization. `int i;` is not initialized `int i = 0;` is. clear?

Comment: Thanks. then the next question is how would I know the outputlength..

Comment: Provide the API you are calling, outputLength may be an output parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you declare

```
size_t outputLength;
```

you are not initializing it. The analyzer does not know that `NewBase64Encode` will set its value, so it's warning you that something might go wrong.

If you are absolutely 100% sure that the value will be initialized later on, then you can safely ignore the analyzer warning, but this is rarely the case. For instance, `NewBase64Encode` might fail and `outputLength` will result uninitialized, leading to undefined behavior.

Is always a good practice to initialize every variable you declare, so in the specific case just do

```
size_t outputLength = 0;
```

The analyzer will be happy and your code safer.

Comment: `length` is not an output parameter in `initWithBytes:length:encoding`. It is an output parameter in `NewBase64Encode`

Answer (score 1):

The warning says exactly the reason:

one of your used arguments is uninitialized. If you explicitely set outputBuffer, outputLength to some default value, the warning will go away.

Comment: I have updated the code with the full method. should I be assigning a value to output straight away?

Comment: yep, set it to 0. The compiler cannot judge, if the &outputLength is initializing the variable (writes to it). Thus it is still flagged as uninitialized when you reach the NSString initializer.